# What is the use of a web.config file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

What is the use of a web.config file in asp.net?

Comment: Search the web, then ask if any confusion. I found a article on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is a configuration file where you store all your application settings. It is XML based.

[web.config demystified](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/web-config-file-demystified/)